# Upgrading from PHP 5 to 7. Array being created with only null value, before it only created an empty array

Tags: php, dbal

I am converting an application from PHP 5 to PHP 7.

Before if $values=null then the value of $values after would be null or an empty array.  Now it seems to be making it
[0=>null]

What has changed?

```
                if(!is_array($values)) {
                        $values = array($values);
                }
```

```
    /**
     * Search for Imaging group report data by sysi code. Optionally
     * specify a Banner username to narrow the search.
     *
     * @param Mixed $sysiCodes
     * @param String $username
     */
    public function searchBySysiCode($sysiCodes, $username = '%', $sort = 'user')
    {
        $imagingModuleDataAccess = new ImagingModuleDataAccess();
        $imagingGroupDataAccess = new ImagingGroupDataAccess();
        $op = '';
        
        /* Retreive modules and build a search string based on the
        specified sysi codes. This is required to ensure we exclude 
        "private" sysi codes and groups that cannot be requested
        for access. */
        $module = null;
        
        if(is_array($sysiCodes))
        {
            foreach($sysiCodes as $sysiCode)
            {
                $module = $imagingModuleDataAccess->searchBySysiCode($sysiCode)->first();
                
                if($module != null)
                {
                    $searchString .= $op . $imagingGroupDataAccess->getGroupMapSearchString($module);
                }
                
                $op = ' or ';
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            $module = $imagingModuleDataAccess->searchBySysiCode($sysiCodes)->first();
            
            if($module != null)
            {
                $searchString = $imagingGroupDataAccess->getGroupMapSearchString($module);
            }
        }
        
        $searchString = " and ( $searchString ) ";
        
        // Add the username if specified.
        if($username != null && $username != '%')
        {
            $searchString .= ' and ae_login.usrnam like upper(?) ';
            $values = $username;
        }
        
        // Add sorting option.
        switch ($sort)
        {
            case 'user':
                $searchString .= ' order by ae_login.usrnam, ae_als.aliasname ';
                break;
                
            case 'group':
            default:
                $searchString .= ' order by ae_als.aliasname, ae_login.usrnam ';
                break;
        }
        
        return $this->search($searchString, $values);
    }
```

```
    /**
     * Function used to access underlying datastore handle
     *
     * @param string $searchString sql where clause for search
     * @param array $values bind values for sql
     * @return mixed return type based on RETURNTYPE code
     */
    protected function search($searchString, $values)
    {
        $return = '';
        
        $sql = "select distinct
                    ae_login.usrnam,
                    ae_als.aliasid,
                    ae_als.aliasname,
                    ae_als.aliasdesc
                from
                    otgmgr.ae_als,
                    otgmgr.ae_login,
                    otgmgr.ae_amap
                where 
                    1 = 1 
                    and ae_amap.usrid = ae_login.usrid
                    and ae_als.aliasid = ae_amap.aliasid 
                    $searchString ";
        try 
        {
            $return = $this->retrieve($sql, $values);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            throw $e;
        }
        
        return $return;
    }
```

```
        protected function retrieve($sql, $values=array())
        {
                // The result set to return.
                $return = '';

                /* Doctrine DBAL */
                if(!is_array($values)) {
                        $values = array($values);
                }

                $stmt = $this->dataSource->executeQuery($sql, $values);

                // Determine what type of result to return.
                if ($this->returnType == RETURNTYPE_RAW) {
                        $return = $stmt;
                } else if ($this->returnType == RETURNTYPE_ARRAY) {
                        $return = $this->getArray($stmt);
                }       else if ($this->returnType == RETURNTYPE_ASSOC) {
                  $return = $this->getAssoc($stmt);
                } else if ($this->returnType == RETURNTYPE_ITERATOR) {
                        $return = $this->getIterator($this->getArray($stmt));
                } else {
                        throw new Exception('Invalid returnType ' . $this->returnType);
                }

                return $return;
        }
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, behaviour hasn't changed. See https://3v4l.org/qnvXI Maybe something has changed in the way you're handling after it's set. There's a lot of code here - highlight a problem area.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing actually changed in this example when comparing PHP 5 vs 7.
As far as I can tell from your code snippets you could pass null value into `retrieve($sql, $values=array())` as second parameter.

This can happen if conditions 
`if($username != null && $username != '%')`

in method 
`searchBySysiCode($sysiCodes, $username = '%', $sort = 'user')`
are not met.
You could define `$values` variable at the begining of `searchBySysiCode` method thus you wouldn't get `null` value into second parameter of `retrieve` method.